# Finding an exact keyword in an excel cells using python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking out for some help here please.  I have two data frames DF1 and DF2. DF1 contains Employee number and their names. DF2 contains Employee number and Comments column. I wanted to find if the  Comments column in DF2 contains the names that are exists in DF1 corresponding to their Emp number unique value. If the name exists in Comments column in DF2 it should return as 'Name exists'. If the name doesn't exists in the comments column it should return as 'Name doesn't exists'

[image]     [image]

Appreciate if someone could help. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex with `\b\b` for words boundaries and `re.escape` if possible some special regex characters:

```
import re
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in DF1['Name'])

DF2['new'] = np.where(DF2['Name'].str.contains(pat), 
                      'Name exist', 
                      'Name does not exist')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jezrael. The above one works if the DF2['comments'] column contains only the name but my column contains a whole bunch of words.